# How to save the state of the jupyter notebook kernel?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter

I am using Azure notebooks for learning python. Recently I stated to learn about MNIST text recognition dataset. Everytime I shutdown the server and restart the kernel after hours of inactivity its takes about 10-15 mins just to import the MNIST dataset.

Is there anyway that kernel just remember my datasets, outputs, variables so it can save alot of time for me.

Thank you

Comment: You can use pickle to store the state of dataset/dataframe, but not in Jupyter itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) library.

This will pickle any python objects, dill also provides ability to save the state of an interpreter session.